# How to make a new filter and apply it on an image using cv2 in python2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

How to make a new filter and apply it on an image using cv2 in python2.7?

For example:

```
kernel = np.array([[-1, -1, -1],
                   [-1,  4, -1],
                   [-1, -1, -1]])
```

i'm new to opencv so if you can explain that'd be great. thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as applying a custom kernel to a given image you may simply use [filter2D](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html) method to feed in a custom filter. You may also copy the following code to get you going. But The results with current filter seem a bit weird:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Create a dummy input image.
canvas = np.zeros((100, 100), dtype=np.uint8)
canvas = cv2.circle(canvas, (50, 50), 20, (255,), -1)

kernel = np.array([[-1, -1, -1],
                   [-1, 4, -1],
                   [-1, -1, -1]])

dst = cv2.filter2D(canvas, -1, kernel)
cv2.imwrite("./filtered.png", dst)
```

Input image:

[image]

Output Image:

[image]

**EDIT:** As per the edits suggested by [@Dolphin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2253101/dolphin), using a kernel with center value of 8, would get the good results in case of circular binary disc.

Comment: In your kernel you have "4" in the middle and "-8" as the sum of the other elements (weights) of the kernel. So put 8 in the middle and also consider that you have set your canvas type to 8-bit unsigned int (integer values from 0 to 255).

Comment: The OP was just asking about the methods and workflow of applying a custom kernel. And I have just copied the kernel from the question itself.

Comment: Right, I was referring to what you said "But The results with current filter seem a bit weird" and your particular test case of a white disk on a black background. So just a remark (for the OP or others), when you change 4 to 8 the results for this specific test case will not be weird and you will see a nice circle.

Comment: Oh your help is appreciated buddy, I have added your suggestions to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can just adapt the code at http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html.
That is an OpenCV 3 page but it will work for OpenCV 2.

The only difference in the code below is how the kernel is set.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('opencv_logo.png')

kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.float32) * (-1)
kernel[1,1] = 8
print(kernel)
dst = cv2.filter2D(img,-1,kernel)

plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img),plt.title('Original')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(dst),plt.title('Filters')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Notice that I have used 8 for the centre pixel instead of 4, because using 4 darkens the results too much. Here is the result from the code above:

[image]