# Image to 2D array conversion takes too long

Tags: python

I have a script that

1. Splits image to blocks then adds up each blocks' pixel color values
2. Divides that value by number of pixels in the block.
3. Then it checks if block's average value is bigger or smaller than 127 and returns either 1 or 0 (if it's black or white); assigns that 0 or 1 to a 2D array.

However this script is extremely slow. Maybe some of you guys would have better idea. Here's my code.

```
#gridHeight and gridWidth is how many blocks vertically and horizontally are there. 
#bialeMin is block's width and height (blocks are always squares)

    for y in range (0, gridHeight):
    for x in range (0, gridWidth):
        i=0
        pixel=0
        for v in range (0, bialeMin):
            for w in range (0, bialeMin):
                pixel=pixel+im.getpixel((((x*bialeMin)+w),((y*bialeMin)+v)))
                i=i+1
        if (pixel/i)<127:
            pixelavg[y][x]=1
        elif (pixel/i)>127:
            pixelavg[y][x]=0
```

Comment: Can you use other functions? This is similar to applying kernels to images, maybe this can help. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685757/how-to-make-a-new-filter-and-apply-it-on-an-image-using-cv2-in-python2-7)

Comment: One way could be to have a look into [numpy](https://numpy.org/). You could extract the blocks directly with subarrays and just call for example `numpy.sum()` on these subarrays without any loops. It's a bit of tricky business to start out, but numpy is highly optimized for array operations (with an image being basically just a 2D-array) and therefore much, much faster than self-written loops.

Comment: @RolandDeschain that seems like a solution, however I don't know how turn image to an array. 
doing so: im2=np.array(im) just gives me zeros everywhere

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but it looks like you already figured it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so thanks to @Roland Deschain I managed to get it working with huuuuge benefit in processing time.

```
im2=np.array(im)
for y in range (0, gridHeight):
for x in range (0, gridWidth):
    i=0
    im3=im2[(y*bialeMin):(y*bialeMin+bialeMin),(x*bialeMin):(x*bialeMin+bialeMin)]
    im4=np.sum(im3) / (bialeMin*bialeMin)
    if im4<127:
        pixelavg[y][x]=1
    elif im4>127:
        pixelavg[y][x]=0
```